# Package scheduled in SQL Server Agent doesn't migrate data correctly

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have SSIS package that connects to particular view in SQL Server A (2008 R2 SP2) and migrates data to the table in SQL Server B (2008 R2 SP2). It is scheduled in SQL Server Agent to run every 60 minutes.
The problem is that the when check the destination table after scheduled migration takes place, 4 float type columns have missing data (but only partially, some records contain the values). But when I execute the same package manually (through **Start job at Step** option or directly via Visual Studio) the data migrates properly and no data is missing. I've checked the Server Agent log, but there are no errors. What could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Try open the package in Visual studio, check if you find warnings or truncation of data, although it is not error

Comment: nope, there are not warnings

Comment: What is an example of missing data, and how can you be sure the data should be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really true that the data migrates properly when you start the job manually using **Start job at Step...**, as you say you do, then the only difference between that and when the Agent runs the job on its schedule is the time the job runs.

Therefore the problem would have to be time-related.  Either the data wasn't there when the agent ran, but it is there when you run it manually, or the agent ran the job at the same time that something else was running that interfered with the data.

Comment: you were correct, changing the time the job is scheduled helped. Apparently there's a job running on source database that I wasn't aware of.